# How does Nodejs worker thread work under the hood?

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, rsa, cpu-usage

I have a nodeJS application that operates on user data in the form of JSON. The size of the JSON data is variable and depends on the user. Usually the size is around 30KB.
Every time any value of the the JSON parameter changes, I recalculate the JSON object, stringify it and encrypt the string using RSA encryption.

Calculating the json involves doing the following steps:

1. From the database get the data required to form the json. This involves querying atleast 4 tables in a nested for loop.
2. Use object.assign() to combine the data to form larger json object in the same for loop of order 2.

Once the final object is formed stringify and encrypt it using crypto module of nodejs.

So all this is causing my CPU to crash when the data is huge which means large number of iterations and lot of data to encrypt.

We use postgres database, hence I have to recalculate the entire json object even if only  a single parameter value changed.

I was wondering if nodejs worker pool could be a solution to this? But I would like to know how the worker threads handles tasks under the hood. Suggestions on an alternate solution to this problem are also welcomed.

Comment: `We use postgres database, hence I have to recalculate the entire json object even if only a single parameter value changed.` You can patch only certain properties in a JSON column. But because you mention `I recalculate the JSON object, stringify it and encrypt the string using RSA encryption.` it seems as if it is due to the encrpytion?

Comment: 30kb does not sound like much data. And `So all this is causing my CPU to crash when the data is huge which means large number of iterations and lot of data to encrypt.` sounds more like you have some other problem in your code. I don't think that using workers will solve that problem. You for sure could utilize more cpu cores with that, but to me, it sounds as if you have a conceptual problem in your code.

Comment: yes json is recalculated because of encryption. entire json is encrypted